# Keeping the loyalty of both Miranda and Jack

Tags: mass-effect-2

According to the [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Miranda_Lawson#Loyalty) it is possible to keep the Loyalty of both Miranda and Jack "if your Paragon or Renegade scores are high enough, you can choose an option favoring neither person and keep the loyalty of both."

How can I determine if my Paragon/Renegade score is sufficient to keep the Loyalty of both characters?

Comment: According to http://au.faqs.ign.com/articles/107/1073018p1.html the option "requires you to have around 75% of the Paragon or Renegade meter."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Paragon/Renegade score has to be at the level just below Max, however if you alienate one of them you do get another chance to get their loyalty back (anytime before you head through the "main" portal), but then your chosen alignment has to be maxed out.

Comment: You need to have a high percentage of all the Paragon/Renegade points from all the areas you have visited so far. The level of the bar has relatively little to do with it.

Comment: I waited until my Paragon points were at least 75% and I had the option to defuse the argument.

Answer (score 3):

Short of actually going through the confrontation to see if you get the option, you can't really tell.

Save before doing the second loyalty mission, so you can revert if you have to.

Comment: Isn't possible to revisit this later on? I have miranda upset with me, but there is a grayed out option in what i can tell her. the excact words escape me though, but its something that seemed like what i would say in the situation.

Comment: You can get her loyalty back, if you earn enough points in Paragon/Renegade. I don't know if this option is time-limited though.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to keep them both reasonably onside, but despite my best efforts I alienated Miranda.

I hoped/figured that I could rebuild the relationship again later in the game, but it never happened (despite saving the miserable wench's ass innumerable times in the game). :(